# Question about Fourier series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fourier-series

Let $$f(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \hat{f}(n) e^{2 \pi i nx},$$ be the Fourier series for $f \in L^2[0,1]$. If $f \neq 0$ almost surely, show that $\{\hat{f}(n+m)\}_{m \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is complete in $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$. In other words the closed span of $\{\hat{f}(n+m)\}_{m \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is dense in $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$. Let $\{\hat{g}(n)\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ be such that $\langle \hat{g}(n), \hat{f}(n+m)\rangle = 0$ for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then, $$0 = \langle \hat{g}(n), \hat{f}(n+m)\rangle = \langle g(x), \sum_n \hat{f}(n+m)e^{2 \pi i nx} \rangle = \sum_n \hat{f}(n+m)\langle g(x),e^{2 \pi inx} \rangle.$$ I have not used the fact that $f \neq 0$ so maybe that should come into play here? I am not sure how to proceed. I know that if $\langle h(x),e^{2 \pi i nx}\rangle = 0$ for all $n$, then we have $h = 0$, so maybe I need to use this here.
Please help.

Thanks :)!

Comment: Hint.  What function $g$ has Fourier series $\hat g(n) = \hat f(n+m)$?

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: I am unsure, would this be some dilated version of the original $f$?

Comment: $g(x) = e^{2 \pi i m x} f(x)$.